# Clean URLgets converted into default url with .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have applied the below code in my .htaccess file which is working but the thing is whenever I browse the clean url (say example.com/shop/) it gets converted into default url 
i:e tt.php?shopname=abc.

Any Idea why this is happening ?

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ ./tt.php?shopname=$1 [L,R,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `R` directive makes it a redirect, so your webserver sends a 301 HTTP redirect answer to the browser. Remove it:

```
[L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: if I remove it,then it will make my Jquery to stop Working.Not sure why this is happening but its not working

Answer (score 0):

You should remove from the end :

```
[L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: If I remove it,then it will make my Jquery to stop Working.Not sure why this is happening but its not working